# Module Not Found, can't resolve slick-carousel/slick/slick.css. I am getting this error when try this reacy-slick on next js project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

When I am developing an app using next js, I try to wondering how I can add some carousel like slick to show some image I need. Following properly the user guide in the official documentation untill I import some css dile needed and it goes to give me an error say that Module Not Found, can't resolve  slick-carousel/slick/slick.css. Whats wrong ? Is that we cant use any react package on next js app ?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Are you using [`react-slick`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-slick) library? If so, make sure to also install `slick-carousel` as it depends on it.

Answer (score 1):

You should also install `npm i slick-carousel` in next js project.

Answer (score 0):

You should also install 'slick-carousel' using the command: npm install slick-carousel.

Comment: This is a comment.